# How do i teleport all players in a server to a part if another humanoid (not a player) has died?

Tags: lua, roblox

so I'm trying to teleport all players in a server to a part if another humanoid has died (not a player) with that I mean like a dummy or a noob.

this is my code:

```
local ghost = game.Workspace[" "]
local part = game.Workspace.Tele2

if ghost.Zombie.Died then

end
```

but i dont know how to teleport the player to the part

here is the npc model:

https://create.roblox.com/marketplace/asset/9117177890/killer-ghost?pageNumber=1&pagePosition=1&keyword=killer+ghost

Comment: As a starting point, check out the [Humanoid.Died signal](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid#Died) for detecting death, [Players:GetPlayers()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetPlayers) for accessing all the players, and [Model:PivotTo()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/PVInstance#PivotTo) for moving characters around.